# Placing a MapLabel on top of a Polygon in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I'm trying to place a MapLabel on top of a Polygon in Google Maps V3. I've tried to set the MapLabel zIndex to 2 and the Polygon zIndex to 1 without any luck. Isn't this possible since the Polygon doesn't really follow zIndex?

I've created a jsFiddle for you guys to check out: http://jsfiddle.net/7wLWe/1/

**Solution:** In `maplabel.js` change:

```
mapPane.appendChild(canvas);
```

to:

```
floatPane.appendChild(canvas);
```

The reason is because `floatPane` is above all map layers (pane 6)

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#OverlayView

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, and accept it, to help others in the future

Comment: Change to markerLayer instead of floatPane if you use draggable or editable.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably a late find.. but hope someone would find this useful.

If you don't want to use `floatPane` (John's Solution) as this will be always on top of everything, and want to give a custom zIndex.. Edit the **maplabel.js**. Add the following line just before the end of **MapLabel.prototype.onAdd = function() {**

```
if (canvas.parentNode != null) {
    canvas.parentNode.style.zIndex = style.zIndex;
}
```

Now you can pass `zIndex` while creating a **maplabel**:

```
var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
    text: "abc",
    position: center,
    map: map,
    fontSize: 8,
    align: 'left',
    zIndex: 15
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to touch `maplabel.js`, you can add this function to change the `z-index` of the parent of the labels (although if you have other `canvas` elements, you may need to alter the function):

```
//change the z-index of the canvas elements parents to move them above polygon layer
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
//var canvasElements = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');//plain js to get the elements
var canvasElements = jQuery('canvas'); //jquery for easy cross-browser support
    for(var i=0; i<canvasElements.length; i++){
        canvasElements[i].parentNode.style.zIndex = 9999;
    }

});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. The parentNode style index change is showing correctly in the inspector but the labels remain hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Great to see that you're using the MapLabel utility library!

As you've found out, the MapLabel sits in a different map pane. `zIndex` is only respected within a certain pane.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maplabel = new MapLabel....  
$(maplabel.getPanes().mapPane).css('z-index', maplabel.zIndex);
```

jQuery made it pretty simple for me without changing maplabel.js
I also found an alternate solution

```
$(maplabel.getPanes().mapPane).addClass('map-pane');
```

and then defining the z-index in a stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

I sketched up this [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/adg29/pen/VaMLrv) utilizing the [gmaps-labels](https://github.com/iamcal/gmaps-labels) class. It is based on the fiddle in the Q above and adds the ose of a `LabelOverlay` class. The class requires a `new google.maps.LatLng`, dimensions (in LatLng units) of a box centered around the label's point (If the label would overflow this box, hide it, and some `CSS`. Heres a code stub, check out the demo in the CodePen.

[image]

```
var MIN_BOX_H = 0.0346, 
    MIN_BOX_W = 0.121,
    MAX_BOX_H = 0.001, 
    MAX_BOX_W = 0.03;



var overlay1 = new LabelOverlay({
    ll      : myLatlng,

    minBoxH     : MIN_BOX_H,
    minBoxW     : MIN_BOX_W,

    maxBoxH     : MAX_BOX_H,
    maxBoxW     : MAX_BOX_W,

   ...

   label        : "I want on top",
   map      : map
});
```