# Changing the opacity of a MapLabel google map utility library

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change to opacity of a mapLabel, but turns out there is no opacity attribute in the reference:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/docs/reference.html

Comment: Are you answering your own question? In that case, you should post your answer as an answer, not part of the question. Also, you might want to have a look at [code formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-code).

Comment: it gave me an error, "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead". Will try fixing the code format

Answer (score 1):

Solution: in maplabel.js add:

```
function MapLabel(opt_options) 
{
    ...
    this.set('opacity',1);
    ...
}
```

and add another:

```
<MapLabel.prototype.changed = function(prop)
{
    switch (prop) {
    ...     
    case 'opacity':
    return this.drawCanvas_();
    ...
    }
}
```

and 1 more:

```
MapLabel.prototype.drawCanvas_ = function() 
{
    ...
    ctx.fillStyle = this.get('fontColor');
    ctx.globalAlpha = this.get('opacity');
    ctx.font = this.get('fontSize') + 'px ' + this.get('fontFamily');
    ...
}
```

this won't solve if you want to search strokeOpacity though...

Oh, and I'm sorry if I didn't do an actual question or anything correctly, first time submitting in stackoverflow to post a solution.

[Placing a MapLabel on top of a Polygon in Google Maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185251/placing-a-maplabel-on-top-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3)

[How to change the opacity (alpha, transparency) of an element in a canvas element after it has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-elemen)