# How to 'mark' an area from the streets/roads around it and place a number in that area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to 'mark' an area with color and place a number in that area:

I have illustrated it here:

[image]

- the numbers are static and don't change.
  The area mark is suppose to change colors. and the area marking suppose to surround the area using the   streets/roads around it(not just plain circle drawing)

I will try to explain myself better, Suppose those numbers are areas that I need to visit..
initially they are colored with red. If I visit one area .. then when i finish the visit the marking is turning to blue color.

Hope I make sense. I don't have any code for that .. I tried to search for it but with no luck

- I'll try to simplify it, I can manage to drop the colors to not change and make it static also
  for that I need to draw on the map some 'areas' **but** from the streets/roads surrounding the area
  only. by that I mean not to draw a line between two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution. Another might be an image overlay but I believe the solution below is more flexible.

You will need: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-map-label@1.0.1/src/maplabel-compiled.min.js

In the above javascript file once you have it, you will also need to change **mapPane.appendChild(a)** to **floatPane.appendChild(a)** this is to get the text on top of the polygon.  As you will see in the following JSFIDDLE the text is underneath the polygon.

**SOLUTION:** http://jsfiddle.net/yN29Z/
**UPDATE June 23: ** http://jsfiddle.net/8oevsrmf/

The above javascript is map_label.js in the code below.

My polygon is not the best but you get the idea.

**UPDATE**: Added color change on clicking the polygon in to code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon Arrays</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="scripts/map_label.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var infoWindow;
        var mypolygon;

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 18,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.71392, -1.983551),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
 
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
            var triangleCoords = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71433, -1.98392),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71393, -1.98239),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71388, -1.98226),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71377, -1.98246),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71332, -1.98296),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71334, -1.98324),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71374, -1.9845),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.71436, -1.98389)];

            // Construct the polygon.
            mypolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: triangleCoords,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35
            });

            mypolygon.setMap(map);

            //Define position of label
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.71392, -1.983551);

            var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
                text: '1',
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                fontSize: 20,
                align: 'left'
            });
            mapLabel.set('position', myLatlng);

            // Add a listener for the click event.  You can expand this to change the color of the polygon
            google.maps.event.addListener(mypolygon, 'click', showArrays);

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        }

        /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
        function showArrays(event) {

        //Change the color here           
        mypolygon.setOptions({ fillColor: '#0000ff' }); 
            
        // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath()
        // to return the MVCArray of LatLngs.
        var vertices = this.getPath();

        var contentString = '<b>My polygon</b><br>' +
      'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
      '<br>';

            // Iterate over the vertices.
            for (var i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
                var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
                contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' + xy.lng();
            }

            // Replace the info window's content and position.
            infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
            infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

            infoWindow.open(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My sources were as follows.

**For the polygon**:
https   ://   developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays

**For the label**
[Placing a MapLabel on top of a Polygon in Google Maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185251/placing-a-maplabel-on-top-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Note that the label doesn't work in browsers that don't support canvas (like IE8) `MapLabel for Google Maps V3 - 
Note that the users browser must support Canvas for the label to be displayed.`

Comment: Just what I needed to get me going :)