# Center a boundary of polygons in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find a better way to center my google map.

I've already written code to add in Markers to Outline and area squarely of which is being store in an array: Coords[i], in-which when returning to the map after save, it centers the map window based on the "first marker" lat/lng coordinates Coords[0].

[image]

I am trying to figure out a better way to center the map where there is adequate space around my outline area.

[image]

I've try doing it on Dragend, which works somewhat:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'dragend', function(mapEvent) {
var lat = mapEvent.getCenter() .lat(),
lng = mapEvent.getCenter() .lng(),

console.log(lat + " " + lng + " " + this);

});
```

But it keeps throwing an error saying:
**"Unable to get property 'getCenter' of undefined or null reference"**

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong OR tell be a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

As, another option

It would be nice if possible if I can keep the first marker [0] the centering marker as it is already, But don't allow it to outline... just the markers [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPeH0.png) + and on .... But I don't know how to modify my code to do that.

Just looking for a solution that works.

My complete Code is here:
http://pastiebin.com/embed/593d6d809e2f0

Comment: Update my question with pics and link to full code

Comment: Are you trying to center on one Polygon? Multiple Polygons? Why do you want to center on dragend? Your question is unclear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps get the center of coordinates (place label at center of polygon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956691/google-maps-get-the-center-of-coordinates-place-label-at-center-of-polygon)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `LatLngBounds` object. Loop through your Polygons if you have more than one and extend your bounds object with each path coordinates.

[`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

You can then make your map fit the bounds object so it will zoom and center accordingly by using `map.fitBounds()`.

[`fitBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

If you use multi-paths Polygon, make sure you use `getPaths` method instead of `getPath` as in the code below.

```js
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        editable: true,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor: '#00FF00',
        fillOpacity: .6,
        paths: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(39, 4),
        new google.maps.LatLng(34, 24),
        new google.maps.LatLng(43, 24),
        new google.maps.LatLng(39, 4)],
        map: map
    });
    
    // Create the bounds object
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Get paths from polygon and set event listeners for each path separately
    polygon.getPath().forEach(function (path, index) {
    
        bounds.extend(path);
    });
    
    // Fit Polygon path bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I just figured out a way!
I simply grabbed the lat/lng coordinates of the center of the polygon drawn and centered my whole map with that.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var i;

//Get Center of Saved Coordinates of the drawn polygons
for (var i = 0; i < values["coords"].length; i++) {

bounds.extend(values["coords"][i]);

}

var movemaplat = bounds.getCenter().lat();
var movemaplng= bounds.getCenter().lng();

console.log("MY MAP CENTER " + movemaplat + ", " + movemaplng);
```

Thanks to @Daniel Vassallo's answer here: [How to get the center of a polygon in google maps v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: That will center your map but that will **not** make sure the entire Polygon will be visible (depends on your zoom level of course). Check my answer for a better solution.