# Google maps how to add MapLabel above maps

Tags: google-maps

I use google map api and add text with MapLabel, how to add text above maps. Now me text under maps.

MapLabel function:

```
    var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
      text: 'Test0000001',
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(61.52401, 105.31875600000001),
      map: map,
      fontSize: 100,
      align: 'center'
    });
```

full code jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/16khyyj0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to replace a line in `maplabel.js` file:

From

```
mapPane.appendChild(canvas);
```

to:

```
floatPane.appendChild(canvas);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9185251/3249477)